# Execute a function after iterating completely over all elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a json object `messages` that I want to display and iterate over using the `map` function. This is loaded at the very beginning. There are 23 elements in it, but it takes a short moment until all elements are displayed. I would like to write a `loading` function, i.e. as soon as all messages have been iterated over, a function should be called.
I have tried this here, but this function is not executed.
Now my question, how can I execute the function `loading`, as soon as over all elements was iterated over?

Note: I have update the message Json and this send also works in real time, but only the initial loading takes too long and therefore I would like to show the user something. A loading bar should be displayed and as soon as the complete list has been iterated over, the list should be removed or no longer displayed and the user should receive the complete loaded list.

```
function MessageSide(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false); // added
  const loading = () => {
    console.log("LOADED")
    setLoaded(true) // added
  }

  return (
      <div class="col flex-fill background--chat">
        <div className="content__body">
         // added
         {loaded? false :
            <div>
                 <Ellipsis color="#5869FF" style={{left:"50", right:"50", top:"50", bottom:"50",}}/>
             </div>
          }                       // added
          <div className="item"  style={loaded? {} : {display: 'none'}}>
            {messages.map((message) => {
              // onLoad={() =>test()} that didn't work
              return (
                <div>
                  <Message
                    message={message.body} 
                    id={message.id}
                    timestamp={message.timestamp}
                    chatid={message.chatid}
                    onLoad={() =>loading()} // this is what I tried
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div ref={messagesEndRef}/>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
export default MessageSide;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading is rather not to be determined in `return`, let alone inside a loop.

You should include code of `<Message>` to your question.

```
const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{ 
  if(message.length > 0) { setInitialLoad(true) } 
},[message]) 
useEffect(()=>{ if(message.length > 0) { 
  /*stop showing loading screen */
} },[initialLoad])`
```

This way, variable initialLoad will be false at first render, but will be changed into true after load. However it will not change afterwards, causing the last useEffect hook to be executed only once

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, I have been able to use this `onLoad()` in an image tag quite easily. Isn't there anything comparable how to do this?

Comment: onLoad() is executed if that single image loaded. However, in your case, you are loading a bunch(list) of data, and you map them. so something equivalent to onLoad() should be listening to the actual loading of the total data, not at the level of each component which are blindly provided with the loaded data.

Comment: However, if you wish to do so, add some code to ```useEffect(()=>{here},[])``` inside Message component, so that it would be executed when the component is rendered, which means that variable ```messages``` is also loaded. 

But beware, since it will be excuted as the length of  ```messages```.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you show me to build something equivalent to the `onLoad()` function?

Comment: I do not know how you load the message data from server, but useEffect can be used to check if there is anything inside message to consider it as loaded.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(message.length > 0) {
    /*whatever you wish to do*/
  }
},[message])
```

Comment: The problem is, if I add another element to my list then this method would be called again? I want to set a `useState` with the method, so that the user is shown a loading bar. I update my question

Comment: So you want to show something while message is being loaded?

```useEffect(()=>{ if(message.length > 0) { /*whatever you wish to do*/ } },[message])```

will do

Comment: btw, approving my answer wil be helpful for those who have the same question in the future.

Comment: Thanks. My concerns are that every time I update the message the loading will are shown. So I would only show the loading at the inital load.

Comment: ```const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(false)```

```useEffect(()=>{ if(message.length > 0) { setInitialLoad(true) } },[message])```

```useEffect(()=>{ if(message.length > 0) { /*stop showing loading screen */} },[initialLoad])```

This will set ```initialLoad``` to true after initial load, but won't to anything thereafter

Comment: could you please update your answer? 
So that it is clearer in the comment section it is just hard to understand :/